# How can I modify this PCB "Solar lamp Mosquito Zapper"?

Tags: solar-cell, lamp

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFXECf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the PCB.
[image: Text]

This is a little schema
[image: Text]

[image: Text]

The function is the solar cell charging the battery (2 x 1.2 V NiMH in parallel), and when the voltage of the solar panel goes down, the Villard cascade charges the capacitor.

I need to make it so that the battery is always charged and always charges the Villard cascade to kill mosquitos.

I don't know what the IC with 5 pins is; the IC does not have any number printed on it. I suppose it is a charge regulator.

EDIT: I supose that the s8550 PNP is cuting of the second stage of the pcb if the voltage of the solar panel is bigger than X volts

Comment: @Carlos can you ask a specific question, you're asking an identification question you need a picture of the component and dimensions

Comment: @VoltageSpike  Sorry, I edited the Post. I need the id of the IC or maybe anyone of you could help me to modify the pcb without know the id of the ic.

Comment: Good job on the schematic. Can you redraw it in some e-CAD program for readability? A built in one exists here, click on edit and the schematic symbol.

Comment: For what it's worth most of those cheap mosquito zapper products don't actually kill mosquitos which are not attracted to light.

Comment: @winny thanks, i will do asap.

Comment: Are there any markings on the IC?

Comment: @VoltageSpike No there arent. The ic and the trafo are unmarked... :(

Comment: The energy balance may be negative if you run the zapper while charging.

Comment: @jens Yes, I know. But if the lamp is designed for run all nigth. Maybe it can run only during the day. This would be a nice improvement. disconect the zapper during the nigth and use another panel to balance the consume